# Windows API - CreateFile() with OPEN_EXISTING set returns error code of ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183)

Tags: c++, winapi, named-pipes, createfile

I am trying to open a named pipe using CreateFile():

```
g_hPipe = CreateFile(szPipeName, 
                    GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 
                    0, 
                    NULL, 
                    OPEN_EXISTING, 
                    FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED, 
                    NULL);
```

where szPipeName looks like `\\\\.\\pipe\\service_name`, and I am getting INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE returned.

[According to the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), the OPEN_EXISTING flag only returns an error if the file doesn't exist, yet `GetLastError()` shows ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183). I know the file exists, that's why I'm using OPEN_EXISTING... The MSDN suggests this only occurs when OPEN_ALWAYS or CREATE_ALWAYS are set. I call `SetLastError(0)` immediately before `CreateFile()` to make sure the `GetLastError()` result is referring to the `CreateFile()` function.

I've searched quite a bit and haven't found anything to suggest why I am receiving this error. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it a duplex (read/write) pipe?

Comment: Here's an example using named pipes, although it doesn't have an answer to your specific question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365592(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, the server creates a duplex pipe.

Comment: Also, as is said many times, `GetLastError()` returning something does nto actually indicate an error occured. You can that from the function preceding it, normally by it returning 0 or some other sentinal value. It is perfectly legal for a function to set the last error value and NOT return failure (see overlapped IO).

Comment: @Deanna it's not just `GetLastError`, the `CreateFile` call returned no handle

Comment: It's worth OP checking that the `GetLastError()` call actually returns the correct code for the NP failure though - nothing happens in between times like logging etc)

Comment: Yes, that was worth looking into. There was indeed a logging statement in between the `CreateFile()` and `GetLastError()` calls that I overlooked. I didn't realize the logging function set a different error. I'll accept your answer as thanks your help.

Comment: great, with karma points for Deanna's pointer.  Glad you are rolling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) indicate you can only `CreateFile` once in a single client, after that you have to duplicate the returned handle:

> If CreateFile opens the client end of a named pipe, the function uses
>   any instance of the named pipe that is in the listening state. The
>   opening process can duplicate the handle as many times as required,
>   but after it is opened, the named pipe instance cannot be opened by
>   another client.

Pipes are a point-to-point transport.  If you want other apps to connect to your server, they will need their own pipe instance, which means another CreateNamedPipe call on the server.

Comment: In that case the CreateFile() should throw a ERROR_PIPE_BUSY though.

Comment: The handle is only created once in the client and reused. The server appears to call `CreateNamedPipe()` each time a thread receives data (it does on first glance at least, it's a rather extensive internal API).

Comment: Yes you're right.  I wonder if the sharing options used are causing problems? ie. the 3rd param being zero when both CreateFile calls use READ | WRITE access?

Comment: Changing the parameter to `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` just produced the same error. Anyways, it shouldn't be the case that there would be multiple clients reading from the pipe.

Comment: Typically the server-side model is for `CreateNamedPipe` to get called after a client connects (completing a `ConnectNamedPipe` callback on the server), which then allows another client to connect